# How can I enforce a standard style for Java code?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to introduce a tool to standardise the format of our java code. The requirements are:

- Required format should be the Oracle standard (or something very very similar)
- Multiline statements should be respected, i.e. if the user adds linebreaks to split a statement over multiple lines in the interest of readability, these should not be removed (see above)
- Gradle integration. If code is submitted that does not conform to the rules, the build should fail.
- Autofixing - reformatting code to conform to the rules via a (Gradle) command
- IDE integration - reformatting code to conform to the rules within IntelliJ, VSCode, etc. [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) might be useful for this.

I've tried using Spotless, but the way it formats multiline statements is very unsatisfactory. For example, the following code

```
var token = Jwts.builder()
        .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
        .setHeaderParam("typ", SecurityConstants.TOKEN_TYPE)
        .setIssuer(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
        .claim("rol", roles)
        .setAudience(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
        .setSubject(user.getUsername())
        .setExpiration(Timestamp.valueOf(tomorrow))
        .addClaims(user.getClaims())
        .compact();
```

Will fail the Spotless checks and if ./gradlew spotlessApply is run, it will be reformatted to this hideous mess

```
var token = Jwts.builder().signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
        .setHeaderParam("typ", SecurityConstants.TOKEN_TYPE).setIssuer(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
        .claim("rol", roles).setAudience(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE).setSubject(user.getUsername())
        .setExpiration(Timestamp.valueOf(tomorrow)).addClaims(user.getClaims()).compact();
```

So effectively, Spotless is behaving almost like an obfuscator. Is there a tool available that can satisfy most/all of the above requirements?

Comment: You can try checkstyle, failing the build will have to handled by your CI.

Comment: @ShivamMohan With spotless we can run the `./gradlew spotlessCheck` command either locally or on the CI to verify if the code is formatted according to the standard

Comment: You would have the same capability with checkstyle, in you IDE as well, what I meant was you will have to define quality gates in your CI, which if violated will fail the build or report accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried using Spotless, but the way it formats multiline statements is very unsatisfactory.

Spotless allows you specify custom rules to fulfill your requirements: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle#custom

[Checkstyle](https://checkstyle.org/) is another a great tool to enforce formatting. It is used by the [Spring Framework](https://github.com/spring-io/spring-javaformat) team. It also has an [excellent plugin for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea).

So suggestion is either:

1. Try writing custom rules for Spotless to fulfill your needs.
2. If (1) is not satisfactory, explore using Checkstyle with custom checks.

> If code is submitted that does not conform to the rules, the build should fail.

There are a couple ways you can handle this:

Whichever format plugin you use, there is a associated `check` task. So for Spotless that would be `spotlessCheck` and Checkstyle is just `check`.

You can configure the `build` task to have a [task dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks) on those tasks.

Another way is to have a check in your pipeline that invokes which check task you configure.